# What's the right way to reply to "Wie geht's"?

Tags: difference, meaning

When using the question "Wie geht's?", what is the difference between the following two replies?

> Gut und ihr?
>   Gut und ihnen?

Comment: Please give a more informative title to your question.

Comment: You mean the difference between "Wie geht es dir?" and "Wie geht es ihnen?"?

Comment: I changed the question to what I think you're asking. But at the same time, I'm voting for close because of general reference. The former one is not grammatical, anyway. — If my understanding of your question is wrong, please rewrite the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you misunderstood the first reply. Nobody would say »Gut, und **ihr**«. You might hear:

> Gut und **dir**?

This means exactly the same as

> Gut und **ihnen**?

Both is in english:

> Good, and how about you?

German has a T-V distinction as described in detail [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction). This article also contains a section with details about [German language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction#German).

Comment: "Gut und" must always be followed by a pronoun in the dative. So "Ihnen" is correct. Intstead of "ihr", it should be "euch" (The dative of the second person informal plural)